# Not exists... except SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Write a SQL query that selects all customers who have accounts at all branches located at Perryridge

I wonder why the answer is

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.customer_name
FROM depositor S
WHERE NOT EXISTS ((SELECT branch_name
                   FROM branch
                   WHERE branch_city = 'Perryridge')
                  EXCEPT
                  (SELECT branch_name
                   FROM depositor D, account A
                   WHERE D.account_number = A.account_number 
                     AND D.customer_name = A.customer_name))
```

instead of

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.customer_name
FROM depositor S
WHERE NOT EXISTS ((SELECT branch_name
                   FROM depositor D, account A
                   WHERE D.account_number = A.account_number 
                     AND D.customer_name = A.customer_name)
                  EXCEPT
                  (SELECT branch_name
                   FROM branch
                   WHERE branch_city = 'Perryridge'))
```

When we write a SQL query that selects all customers who have accounts at all branches located at Perryridge, shouldn't it be the all account the customer have except the account in Perryridge. Then, since it is not exists all account the customer have except the account in Perryridge, it have all the account in Perryridge?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

The first query is correct.
When you do A except B you keep all items from A that are not included in B.

So if it does exists some record that is from Perryridge but does not have an account, you should remove it.

In other words, you should no take in considerations a record if it exists a branch from Perryridge with no account associated.

Comment: I am still confused since B contains all A, so when A except B returns empty.

Comment: A except B would return empty if all the depositors  have account in all branches from Perryridge.

If a depositor is missing an account from at least one branch that join would not be in B , so A except B would not be empty.

So what the query do is get all depositors records that have account in all branches.